# how can I calc pow of fractions or nth root square in numpy?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, pow

I'm trying to calculate the 8th root square of a value or its ^1/8, but numpy is always returning the wrong value

```
temp = 141.18
h2 = temp ** (1/8)
h2_ = np.power(temp, (1/8))
```

my output is always 1.0 .
I've tried square command too.
I need to use numpy, I'm using other numpy arrays in mycode, just to keep compatible.

Comment: maybe you can try with `1./8.`?!!

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> 1/8
0
>>> 1./8
0.125
```

And of course, anything to the power of 0 results in 1.

Answer (score 1):

Understand the numeric tower.

**Rule 1**: Given two operands of the same type, the result will have that type.

e.g. int / int = int

`temp**(1/8)` does not give the 8th root of temp because:

```
>>>1/8
0
```

**Rule 2**: If the operands are mixed, one of them will be coerced up the numeric tower: integer --> rational --> float --> complex.

e.g. float / int = float

```
>>>1./8 # 1. is a float 
0.125
```

**Note**: There may be cases where these rules do not apply to true division / and floor division // but I don't fully understand them. See the [link](https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/application-development/9781784390341/2/ch02lvl1sec16/the-numeric-tower).

"They've done studies you know. It works 60% of the time... everytime." - Brian Fantana

**Trap**: In the OPs question the expression `temp**(1/8)` is made of mixed operands (temp is a float) so why isn't `(1/8)` a float?

The operands are evaluated according to BODMAS/BIDMAS so `(1/8)` is evaluated first, the resulting expression becomes `temp**0` and at this point `0` is coerced to a float.

Any positive `int` or `float` to the power `0.0` is `1.0`.